# What does it mean to "run something in a shell profile"

Tags: bash, shell, path, homebrew, .bash-profile

I'm installing Homebrew and I get a message that says:

> Next steps:
> ⁃ To add Homebrew to your PATH run `brew shellenv` in your shell profile (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile`)"

What does it mean to run something in my shell profile? How do I run `brew shellenv` if it's not in my PATH in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just telling you to run the command in the shell (and as the identity) you want to interact with Homebrew from.

from [man brew](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage),

> shellenv [bash|csh|fish|pwsh|sh|tcsh|zsh]
>
> Print export statements. When run in a shell, this installation of Homebrew will be
> added to your PATH, MANPATH, and INFOPATH.
>
> The variables HOMEBREW_PREFIX, HOMEBREW_CELLAR and HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY
> are also exported to avoid querying them multiple times. To help
> guarantee idempotence, this command produces no output when Homebrew’s
> bin and sbin directories are first and second respectively in your
> PATH. Consider adding evaluation of this command’s output to your
> dotfiles (e.g. ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zprofile on macOS and ~/.bashrc
> or ~/.zshrc on Linux) with: eval "$(brew shellenv)"
>
> The shell can be specified explicitly with a supported shell name
> parameter. Unknown shells will output POSIX exports.

So, while the sentence you quote isn't the best I've ever seen, `brew shellenv`
will configure your shell profile to include `brew` on the `PATH` and add a number of other required shell variables. basically all they are saying is "run this command as yourself, so that it can modify your preferred shell's profile file (like your bash or zsh profile)".